# mvc error JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have added following `scripts` to my `layout.cshtml`

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 ..
 .. other scripts
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

I have following files in `bundleconfig.cs`

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

I have created one `view` which contains

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("editprofile", "Profile", 
    new AjaxOptions 
    { 
        HttpMethod = "POST", 
        OnComplete = "demo.common.getresultData" 
    }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

When I click on `form` `submit` button it giving me following error

> 0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

I searched a lot for this error.There are lot's of links are there, but could not solved my problem. Here is my error screen shot

[image]

Here is my `jquery` file with version.

- jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js
- jquery-1.10.2.js
- jquery-1.10.2.min.js

I stuck with this problem. How can I solve this?

### Edit

When I click on submit button it is not calling editprofile **controller** method.

Script screenshot

[image]

Comment: At a rough guess it looks like you're trying to parse JSON that has an illegal character in it, and you can't do that.

Comment: Are you saying jquery.js has both jquery-1.10.2.js _and_ jquery-1.10.2.min.js in it?

Comment: @BryantMiano please see my edit. I have added `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` instead of `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: @Andy I am getting this error when I click on submit button from ajax form.

Comment: try changing it to `OnComplete = "demo.common.getresultData();"`

Comment: @DLeh I tried it but nt worked. :(

Comment: What version of jquery unobtrusive validation are you using?

Comment: @BryantMiano I have added scripts screenshot. Please see my edit.

Comment: I'm almost certain it's a versioning conflict with jquery/ jquery plugins (probably jquery validate or validate unobstrusive since error is happening on form submit).   I would try updating your jquery nuget packages (if that's possible) or reinstalling them in your project.

Comment: How Can I update jquery by nugget package? is there any nuget package console command for this?

Comment: Install-Package jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive

Comment: @BryantMiano It's working now. I have just run `Update-Package` command from nuget package console. It updated missing packages along with the package that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Run `Update-Package` command from nuget package console to update all missing packages. It update existing package to newer version. nice way to update to latest one.